# Creating Valid JSON with PHP Arrays and Loop

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm messing about with FB Messenger and trying to send a 'list' back, this has to be created with a mySQL lookup and loop.

The correct JSON to send back is defined on Facebook Developers [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/template/generic/).

What I cannot understand is how with PHP I create the 'header' and 'footer' of the object, I have made a loop to put the main content into an array using my database results:

```
$messagePayload = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $messagePayloadC = array();
    $messagePayloadC['title'] = $row['Name'].";
    $messagePayloadC['item_url'] = $row['link'];
    $messagePayloadC['image_url'] = $row['Image'];
    $messagePayloadC['subtitle'] = "$".$row['Price'].";
    $messagePayloadC['buttons']['type'] = "web_url";
    $messagePayloadC['buttons']['url'] = $row['link'];
    $messagePayloadC['buttons']['title'] = "Go!";
    $messagePayload[] = $messagePayloadC;
}

echo var_dump(json_encode($messagePayload))."<p>";
```

What I need to do is add all of the missing peices at the start and end. The output of my array gives:

```
{"title":"My Television","item_url":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/","image_url":"product-image.jpg","subtitle":"$5","buttons":{"type":"web_url","url":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/","title":"Go!"}}
```

The missing header for example is:

```
"attachment": {
  "type": "template",
  "payload": {
    "template_type": "list",
    "top_element_style": "compact",
    "elements": [
```

Am I going about this in the wrong way ?

Comment: Then you must create those elements in your PHP data, either an object or array with all the required data in it

Comment: You also have a stray `"` in this line `$row['Name'].";`

Comment: And this line `"$".$row['Price'].";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly twice in fact

Comment: @delboy1978uk Yea. Beat you to it :) :) :)

Comment: lolz :-P be fast or be last

Comment: @RiggsFolly Create an object for the header and for the footer and then ? Join them together before json_encode ? Yeah, sorry have taken out some extra db results for clarity - stray "

Comment: Thats about the size of it, yea